# Migration of hard drive from one raid array to another

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, raid

I would like to remove a working drive in a raid-1 array, replacing with a new drive, in order to hopefully build a "test system" where I can experiment with OS upgrades and migration of an old "point-of-sale" enterprise software for which we have no original installation disks. I have also been unable to upgrade drivers on current system and would like to upgrade to a current, stable CentOS that our software will run on.

Origin system is Dell PowerEdge 410 running CentOS 5.11 and raid card is Serial-Attached SCSI SAS 6/iR. "Test" system is a Dell Optiplex 360 with a Dell PERC 6i card.

Can I create a "duplicate" raid array this way if I rebuild using removed disk and bypass initialization? If so, I will also duplicate our BackupEdge set-up with a NAS device (all of this on a separate LAN and WAN, of course) so I can then "experiment away", as I fully expect to create a few Linux "pieces that I can keep" during the learning process! (newb/determined hobbyist/family store I.T. guy)

My first posted question and I appreciate any help!

PS - Next question will be regarding how, if at all poss to re-install the pieces and resolve the dependencies of our old P.O.S. program to an OS that is NOT End of Life...

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of "breaking" the RAID to build another one is an interesting one, if anything. But, it's likely to be fraught with horrors.

The simple thing to do here is to use a cloning program on a boot disc(CloneZilla, Acronis, etc.) and clone the existing volume to a single hard drive. Then insert the cloned drive in to your test server. There is no reason to have a second RAID array for simple testing.

If for some reason you need to build another RAID array, take the cloned hard drive and your cloning software boot disc, and clone the drive onto another healthy RAID volume. So, two clones: Old RAID -> Single HD -> New RAID.

Good luck! Make sure you have backups of everything. I don't want to see your next post be how to recover a corrupt RAID volume with an obsolete OS and archaic PoS system. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Appleoddity.  Funny thing - the idea of duplicating the system was to figure out how to update/upgrade our server w/o breaking it and before it crashes.  Well, Mr. Murphy got involved and I now have a running, broken system on my hands. OMSA was reporting an outdated SAS 6i/r driver which I was unable to update and after a few days of normal operation, I checked OMSA  and it now reports "No storage controllers detected" (GUI and CLI). I am still getting successful nightly full system backups to a NAS device and all seems normal. Is it poss to rebuild raid w/o shutdown?